# format dates to be used in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a csv file with 70,000 records and I need to compare dates.

These are currently stored for example DD/MM/YYYY

I believe that sqlite requires them to be stored YYYY-MM-DD so that I can use date functions on them.

Is there any easy way to convert the format of all of these records?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get something like Notepad++ / Textpad and do a search and replace:

```
Textpad    \([0-9]{2}\)/\([0-9]{2}\)/\([0-9]{4}\)
Notepad++  ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})

Replace with: \3-\2-\1
```

Make sure you're searching with regular expressions/extended searching

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have downloaded notepad++ and have tried to do a find using the regular expression you provided and it returns nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Updated to account for differences between Textpad and Notepad++

Comment: No worries, each editor seems to handle them slightly differently

Answer (score 1):

did you try `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', colNameHere)`?

[**More Formatting Information Here**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)